# stmaryrd.sty problems

Tags: packages

I used to have `stmaryrd.sty` installed in my TeX distribution, but I recently had to reinstall my distribution.  I am now unable to sucessfully use [`stmaryrd`](http://ctan.org/pkg/stmaryrd) package.  I downloaded a new copy, and I placed it in the same folder as my `.tex` file, but it doesn't find anything when I try to compile.  Is there any suggested course of action?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What TeX distribution are you using? It's rarely needed to do manual installation, distributions always provide subpackages for the task.